# Problema con INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, nodejs

Estoy usando `INNER JOIN` para listar los `demos` y su `descripcion`, pero ahora necesito agregar a esta info los `tags` los cuales se guardan en una tabla `tags` con un `name` y un `demo_id` que seria la forma de asociar cada tag con su demo ya que esta seria la misma que `id` de la tabla `demos`.

Intente hacer esta consulta y tecnicamente funciona, pero lo que hace es por ejemplo si hay 2 tags para ese demo repetirme el demo 2 veces con cada tag.

```
SELECT `i`.`name`, 
       `i`.`id`, 
       `i`.`img`, 
       `i`.`cat_id`, 
       `d`.`description`, 
       `d`.`url`, 
       t.name as tags 
FROM `demos` i 
INNER JOIN `details` d ON `i`.`id` = `d`.`demo_id` 
INNER JOIN tags t ON t.demo_id = i.id 
ORDER BY `i`.`id` ASC
```

El resultado que devuelve esto es:

```js
[
  {
    "name": "asdasda",
    "id": "a12qdv",
    "img": "https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/demos/1490127164214",
    "cat_id": 0,
    "description": "asdas",
    "url": "http://asd/cms/demos",
    "tags": "ReactJS"
  },
  {
    "name": "asdasda",
    "id": "a12qdv",
    "img": "https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/demos/1490127164214",
    "cat_id": 0,
    "description": "asdas",
    "url": "http://asd/cms/demos",
    "tags": "PHP"
  }
]
```

Lo que necesito que devuelva, supongamos que hay 3 demos:

```js
[
  {
    "name": "asdasda",
    "id": "a12qrgw21dv",
    "img": "https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/demos/1490127164214",
    "cat_id": 0,
    "description": "asdas",
    "url": "http://asd/cms/demos",
    "tags": "ReactJS, JavaScript"
  },
  {
    "name": "asdasda",
    "id": "a12qdv",
    "img": "https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/demos/1490127164214",
    "cat_id": 0,
    "description": "asdas",
    "url": "http://asd/cms/demos",
    "tags": "PHP, ReactJS"
  },
   {
    "name": "asdasda",
    "id": "1231f2q21dv",
    "img": "https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/demos/1490127164214",
    "cat_id": 0,
    "description": "asdas",
    "url": "http://asd/cms/demos",
    "tags": "PHP, NodeJS, Phyton"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con esto:

```
SELECT `i`.`name`, 
       `i`.`id`, 
       `i`.`img`, 
       `i`.`cat_id`, 
       `d`.`description`, 
       `d`.`url`,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t.name SEPARATOR ', ') as tags
FROM `demos` i 
INNER JOIN `details` d ON `i`.`id` = `d`.`demo_id` 
INNER JOIN tags t ON t.demo_id = i.id 
GROUP BY `i`.`id`
ORDER BY `i`.`id` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer un group by que incluyera toda la query, o podrías hacer una tabla derivada de la forma

```
SELECT demo_id, GROUP_CONCAT(name) as names GROUP BY demo_id
```

Y tu query quedaría

```
SELECT `i`.`name`, 
       `i`.`id`, 
       `i`.`img`, 
       `i`.`cat_id`, 
       `d`.`description`, 
       `d`.`url`, 
       t.names as tags 
FROM `demos` i 
INNER JOIN `details` d ON `i`.`id` = `d`.`demo_id` 
INNER JOIN (SELECT demo_id, GROUP_CONCAT(name) as names GROUP BY demo_id) t ON t.demo_id = i.id 
ORDER BY `i`.`id` ASC
```